# Fullcalendar gotoDate method from a button click

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

Using Fullcalender.io, I can render a calendar fine and also use the gotoDate method which instantly skips to 2010.  However, I don't seem to be able to use the gotoDate method to skip to another date (2018 in this case) on a button click.  How do I correctly call this method?

```
<html lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <script>

      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
        var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
          initialView: 'dayGridMonth'
        });
        calendar.render();
        calendar.gotoDate('2010-01-01');
      });

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <button class="testbut" id="testbut">Skip to 2018</button>
    <div id='calendar'></div>
    
    <script>
       $(document).ready(function(){
         $('.testbut').click(function(){
           $("#calendar").fullCalendar("gotoDate","2018-01-01");
         });
       });
    </script> 
    
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/az4h31py/1/

Comment: `calendar.gotoDate` != `$("#calendar").fullCalendar("gotoDate`. fullCalendar is not a jQuery plugin (anymore). Unclear why you randomly used two different syntaxes for this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this . Just declare the `calendar` variable globally and use that to call the function anytime you want.

https://jsfiddle.net/syact05p/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <script>
    var calendar
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
        calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
          initialView: 'dayGridMonth'
        });
        calendar.render();
        calendar.gotoDate('2010-01-01');
      });

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <button class="testbut" id="testbut">Skip to 2018</button>
    <div id='calendar'></div>
    
    <script>
       $(document).ready(function(){
         $('.testbut').click(function(){
           calendar.gotoDate('2018-01-01');
         });
       });
    </script> 
    
    
  </body>
</html>
```